# How can I simplify a 'pixelated' raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I generate a Vegetation Index (VI) with a script and write the resulting 2d array into a .TIF file. When I load it into QGIS, I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the raster looks very 'granular'. I would like to simplify the raster by grouping large groups of pixels and removing very small 'islands' of pixels. Is there a tool in QGIS available to do this?

EDIT:
I am using the suggested Majority Filter of SAGA. In the log, I get the following error however:

```
QGIS version: 3.16.4-Hannover
Qt version: 5.12.8
GDAL version: 3.2.1
GEOS version: 3.9.0-CAPI-1.16.2
PROJ version: Rel. 7.2.1, January 1st, 2021
SAGA version 7.3.0 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Majority filter' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : '/home/sytze/Code/DeepLabV3Plus_implementation-single-class/my_mask.tif', 'MODE' : 0, 'RADIUS' : 1, 'RESULT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'THRESHOLD' : 0 }

grid_filter "Majority Filter" -INPUT "/tmp/processing_DbxJIV/824e2db5d3434b009d4140e50b49825a/mymask.sgrd" -MODE 0 -RADIUS 1 -THRESHOLD 0 -RESULT "/tmp/processing_DbxJIV/a99c9a0147ce45679fcee5414f3d266f/RESULT.sdat"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.3.0


Library: Filter
Category: Grid
File: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/saga/libgrid_filter.so
Description:
Tools for the manipulation of gridded data.

Tools:
[0] Simple Filter
[1] Gaussian Filter
[2] Laplacian Filter
[3] Multi Direction Lee Filter
[4] User Defined Filter
[5] Filter Clumps
[6] Majority/Minority Filter
[7] DTM Filter (slope-based)
[8] Morphological Filter
[9] Rank Filter
[10] Mesh Denoise
[11] Resampling Filter
[12] Geodesic Morphological Reconstruction
[13] Binary Erosion-Reconstruction
[14] Connectivity Analysis
[15] Sieve Classes
[16] Wombling (Edge Detection)
[17] Wombling for Multiple Features (Edge Detection)
[18] Simple Filter (Restricted to Polygons)


Tool Chains: Grid Filters
Description:
Filters for grids.


Tools:
[SieveAndClump] Sieve and Clump
[grid_notch_filter] Notch Filter for Grids
[grid_list_simple_filter] Simple Filter for Multiple Grids

Error: select a tool
type -h or --help for further information

Execution completed in 0.57 seconds
Results:
{'RESULT': '/tmp/processing_DbxJIV/a99c9a0147ce45679fcee5414f3d266f/RESULT.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /tmp/processing_DbxJIV/27317bdae6e44f098ae6f732f727637c/RESULT.sdat
• /tmp/processing_DbxJIV/a99c9a0147ce45679fcee5414f3d266f/RESULT.sdat
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SAGA majority filter](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/grid_filter_6.html) can do that: `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Majority filter`

[image]

See also this answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/153908/88814

Another option is the GRASS tool `r.neighbors`. You might use the result togeter with your original picture in the raster calculator. For testing, I used your screenshot:

[image]

See result:
[image]

If you apply raster calculator over this result with an expression like `"output@1"  != 0`, you get a black=0 and white=1 ("boolean") raster. Again using raster calculator, you can multiply your original image with this "boolean" raster to get black values where the boolean is black and leaving the rest as it is.

[image]

*Result of combining the two rasters with raster calculator. Running raster calculator, you have to repeat this per band and than recombine the separate RGB bands back to a multiband image:*
[image]

*Before (left) and after (right): each band of the original input raster was multiplied with the "boolean" raster. The three separate files were than merged with `Menu Processing / Toolbox /  GDAL / Raster miscellaneous / Merge` (or: `Menu Raster / Miscellaneous /Merge`). This generates a 3-band output raster. Be sure to make settings (min/max values for red, green, blue bands) the same as in the original to get the same look as in the original input:*
[image]

*From the "boolen" raster, you can easily create contour polygons: `Menu Processing / Toolbox / GDAL / Raster extraction / Countour polygons` (needs GDAL 2.4.0 or later). If Contour polygons does not appear in you QGIS processing toolbox, simply select `Contour` and set the parameter `-p`, see [GDAL help](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_contour.html#cmdoption-gdal_contour-p). In the following screenshot, I created to blue polygons from the "boolean" raster:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This indeed seems like the proper tool. However, I run into errors using the tool (see edited post).

Comment: See updated answer. For further problems, it could help to get a sample of your data.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is what I was looking for.