# Smoothing of shared edges as result of Raster to Polygons/Contour to Polygon Tool

Tags: qgis, raster, smoothing

Based on a 15m DEM, I have created a Slope Raster, converted to polygons, calculated the slope bands and assigned a value, dissolved based on this value field and now I want to smooth the shared edges to create a better looking result.

I have tried the “Smooth” tool but end up with gaps between polygons.

I have also tried the GRASS v.generalize but when I run it on my dissolved vector polygon layer I get an empty output and multiple errors while running the tool.

I thought I could reclassify using the Raster Calculator using the following:

```
("Slope@1" <= 10)*10 +
("Slope@1" > 10 AND "Slope@1" <= 22)*20 +
("Slope@1" > 22)*30
```

I then used the “Contour to Polygon” tool with an interval of 10 which produces the following result.  Its better but not exactly what I was after.

[image]

I have used the “Contour to Polygon” tool with an interval of 10 on the raw Slope raster and I get the following which is way nicer. Not not sure if I should be using it on the raw Slope Raster though considering the bands I am after are < 10, 10-22, > 22?

[image]

15m DEM
[image]

Polygon layer (raster to polygon)

[image]

Comment: Maybe SAGA majority filter? See here if this does help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396622/88814

Comment: The term that you are looking for is called "simplification".

Comment: Thanks.  I will have a look at the SAGA majority filter

Comment: I dont understand what you are starting with. The third screenshot? I does not look like a proper [DEM](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//WORKING/BRWS/Browse.001/2019.06.26/ASTGTMV003_N10E000.1.jpg?_ga=2.159107000.344140723.1565008229-1371303444.1563801461). It looks like a RGB raster where each color is a height?