Change Value of Cell in Cost Layer (Raster) by whether it touches neighbouring cell
QGIS 3.36-Maidenhead: I have compiled a very large cost raster covering parts of Africa. I have applied cost values to all cells based on geographical considerations.
I'd like to carry out a final modification to this raster. For example, change the value of every green cell (currently value 3) that touches a blue cell (value 1) to a new value of 6. This is a task for the Raster Calculator? Its beyond my current expertise.


Not sure what exactly you want to achieve, maybe a majority filter is what you're looking for? See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396622/88814

Is the raster to large to vectorize?

I don't want to vectorise - it must remain as a raster. Its for Least Cost Path purposes.

No, it doesn't have to remain as raster. You can vectorize, conduct neighbour analysis then rasterize the result back to new cost raster.  However, it should be possible to stay completely as raster to do the neighbour analysis, can you share a small sample to test with please?

I've just added a sample of the raster above @user2856

MyFrictionlayer.tifDownload from: https://mbf.cc/IfKZvo

This can be done as a raster analysis, with no need to vectorize, in two steps using the GRASS processing tools in QGIS:

Run r.neighbors with "minimum" neighbor operation and neighborhood size of 3x3


Run r.mapcalc.simple with the minimum neighbors as layer "A" and your cost raster as layer "B" and the expression:
if((A==1) && (B==3), 6, B)




Input:

Result:



Vectorize the raster: Raster pixels to polygons

Select the cells representing the blue pixels, based on the value, with select by expression

Apply a buffer of the same size as the pixel size only to the selected cells only and dissolve the buffer

Re-Rasterize the buffered polygons with a value of 3: Rasterize (vector to raster)

Fill NoData cells with value 0

Use the re-rasterized buffer with raster calculator and the following expression, where rasterized is the name of the raster layer from step 5:
if ( "rasterized@1" = 3 and "MyFrictionlayer@1" = 1 , 6, "MyFrictionlayer@1")


Result, based on the sample data you provided: left - initial state, right - the solution with red pixels corresponding to formarly blue pixels that touch green pixels:

